# Windows does not recognize my monitor any more

Tags: windows, graphics-card, windows-8.1, dvi, amd-radeon

I was running Windows 8.1 on a Intel i7 with an Asus Radeon 270X connected to a Yamakasi Q271 display at 2560x1440 via DVI.

Everything was totally fine until today. When i powered up my Computer in the morning, the desktop resolution was stuck at 640x480 (Catalyst Control Center reports 640x480 as the maximum supported resolution). I can increase to 1920x1080 but only using "List all modes".

The funny thing is that it works when i connect it using a HDMI cable. I already tried to reinstall the driver, to reinstall the monitor driver, completely disconnecting from power, i even replugged the graphics card.

Any ideas what i could try to get it back at the native 2560x1440?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the HDMI cable? I'd take a guess and say that the DVI port on the monitor is toast for some reason. If the HDMI works, just use that. If the video card only outputs DVI, consider a DVI->HDMI adapter. I have seen the DVI port crap out on a monitor before, without apparent provocation, so this isn't entirely without precedent.

Comment: Have you tried a different DVI cable?

Comment: Thanks for your input. The reason i don't want to use HDMI is that sometimes i use the screen with my notebook and i can switch between my desktop and my notebook simply by changing the source.

Comment: Trying a different cable is a good idea! I just don't have a spare dual link cable at the moment, but i'm going to get one tomorrow.